# incompatible types: inference variable T has incompatible bounds

Tags: java, java-8

I have the following piece of code

```
public int solution(int X, int[] A) {

    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(A);
```

For some reason it's throwing the following compilation error

> Solution.java:11: error: incompatible types: inference variable T has
>   incompatible bounds
>           List list = Arrays.asList(A);
>                                             ^
>       equality constraints: Integer
>       lower bounds: int[]   where T is a type-variable:
>       T extends Object declared in method asList(T...)

I assume this a Java 8 feature, but I'm not sure how to resolve the error

Comment: Use `Integer[]` instead of `int[]`.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

`Arrays.asList` is expecting a variable number of `Object`. `int` is not an `Object`, but `int[]` is, thus `Arrays.asList(A)` will create a `List<int[]>` with just one element.

You can use `IntStream.of(A).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: Note that the IntStream approach has slightly different semantics than using asList; changes to the underlying array are not reflected in the resulting list. (so there is a copy of some sort going on).  asList(T...) does no copying.  I don't know of any way around that, unfortunately.

Comment: @rcreswick Interesting, did not know that. However, _if_ this behaviour is expected, then there's probably really no way to achieve it with an `int[]`, as the `int[]` could not be the backing array of the resulting `List<Integer>`.

Comment: I've been trying to find a way to achieve this, and I think the only way is to create a new list type that manages the accesses to reuse a backing array, which would likely obviate the general performance improvements your hope for by using a backing array.

Answer (score 18):

In Java 8 you can do

```
List<Integer> list = IntStream.of(a).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no shortcut for converting from int[] to List as Arrays.asList does not deal with boxing and will just create a List which is not what you want. You have to make a utility method.

```
int[] ints = {1, 2, 3};
List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int index = 0; index < ints.length; index++)
{
    intList.add(ints[index]);
}
```