# java: incompatible types: inference variable U has incompatible bounds

Tags: java, java-8, akka

> Error:(65, 52) java: incompatible types: inference variable U has incompatible bounds
>   equality constraints: akka.http.javadsl.model.HttpResponse
>   lower bounds: com.myactors.ChatActor.ChatMessage

The following line compiles shows error :

```
 CompletionStage<HttpResponse> httpResponse =
                        postChat(url,
                                context().system(), chatData)
                                .thenApplyAsync(httpResponse -> new ChatActor.ChatMessage(httpResponse,"1234"));


public static class ChatMessage{
   HttpResponse httpResponse;
    String name;

    public ChatMessage( HttpResponse httpResponse, String name) {
        this.httpResponse = httpResponse;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public HttpResponse getHttpResponse() {
        return httpResponse;
    }

    public String getname() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Here is HttpResponse is of Akka Http.

I dont know what it is saying.
What should the way to resolve it?

Comment: show your class ChatMessage

Comment: where thenApplyAsync is coming from?

Comment: @avy : The question is not clear, you might need to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27522741/incompatible-types-inference-variable-t-has-incompatible-bounds

Answer (score 0):

The method `.thenApplyAsync(httpResponse -> new ChatActor.ChatMessage(httpResponse,"1234"))` returns a `CompletionStage<ChatActor.ChatMessage>` rather than `CompletionStage<HttpResponse>`, as with your function `httpResponse -> new ChatActor.ChatMessage(httpResponse,"1234")`, you are converting the instance of type `HttpResponse` to an instance of type `ChatActor.ChatMessage`.

So simply change the variable’s type:

```
CompletionStage<ChatActor.ChatMessage> httpResponse =
     postChat(url, context().system(), chatData)
    .thenApplyAsync(httpResponse -> new ChatActor.ChatMessage(httpResponse,"1234"));
```

The reason why the compiler doesn’t simply say “*cannot assign an instance of type `CompletionStage<ChatActor.ChatMessage>` to a variable of type `CompletionStage<HttpResponse>`*” lies in the new type inference applied to the generic method [`thenApplyAsync`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#thenApplyAsync-java.util.function.Function-). The compiler tries to find a type for the method’s type parameter `U` that could make the invocation valid, i.e. if there was a subtype relationship between `ChatActor.ChatMessage` and `HttpResponse`, it would be possible. Since this fails, the compiler tells you that it can’t find a valid type for `U`.