# "Incompatible types" error when using collect and map with java streams

Tags: java, stream

I have this class:

```
public class AirbnbListing {
...
private int price
...
public int getPrice() { return price; }
```

And I'm trying to use a java stream to collect the integer prices from an ArrayList of AirbnbListing objects:

```
ArrayList<AirbnbListing> properties = dataParser.getNeighbourhoodProperties(neighbourhood, 0, -1, 0, "All");
ArrayList<Integer> prices =
    properties.stream()
        .map(AirbnbListing::getPrice)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But I'm getting "Incompatiable types: inferenance variable R has incompatible bounds". Not sure what the issue is.

Comment: change `ArrayList<Integer> prices` to `List<Integer> prices`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27522741/incompatible-types-inference-variable-t-has-incompatible-bounds

Answer (score 0):

Create `ArrayList` By passing argument like.

```
ArrayList<Integer> prices =
    properties.stream()
        .map(AirbnbListing::getPrice)
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));//<------- this
```